# Canadian data and iOS push notiifcations

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I've inherited an application that works with data for Canadian schools.  One aspect of this application is that we have a feature that lets us push notifications to parents using iOS push notifications.  We have a legal requirement that none of the personally identifying information we work with leaves Canada.

From what I've read, iOS push notifications go through api.push.apple.com, which I'd assume resides in the US.  Is there a Canadian server that we can use instead?

Comment: the actual content is supposed to be encrypted so you don't need to worry about privacy too much.

Comment: Correct. This would be like worrying about the router hops in between packets for SSL/HTTPS traffic.

Comment: Not to mention customers who receive data using a VPN or who are outside of Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should design your application such that no *sensitive/private data should not be sent through push notifications*. It should contain generic statements such as "*Important information available regarding Mathematics exam of student.*" or "Results available for examination held last week !!"

You should download specific data once parent opens the app

Comment: I think this really is the best solution for me.  I completely understand where my customers are coming from here.  They have a responsibility to their students on how that data is handled and protected.  While it stays in Canada, it's covered by Canadian law.  Likewise, in this particular situation, there is no guarantee about what Apple (or Google for our Android using parents) is doing with that data.